# How could I attach .mp3 file to my question?

Tags: support, feature-request

I have a question about the pacing of voice in Google Assistant through Google Actions API. Which I'm going to post on http://stackoverflow.com. But I need to attach an audio file for example purposes, in additional to SSML snippet.

So how could I do it?

I know that I can upload it to one host and make a link to it. But I'd like that people would be able to play sound without leaving the Stack Overflow page.

As well I'll attach code which would be needed to reproduce this file.

## Why do we need audio on Stack Overflow

Because of many questions about - *why do we need audio here on Stack Overflow.*

I'll give an explanation:

Google [recommends](https://developers.google.com/actions/support/) Stack Overflow as the first place where developers should ask questions about Actions on Google . So I thought that maybe Stack Overflow supports audio file attachments because it would be very useful for audio related questions.

And sure it is not only about Google but any audio generation API, algorithms, standards (SSML) and etc. All that could be related to audio interfaces they all could require audio examples because it is their working material.

Comment: Am I the only one who finds the idea of Stack Overflow making noises at me rather frightening?

Comment: @JoeC maybe it can do like Alexa and start randomly laughing? That ain't creepy, right?

Comment: Okay - I'll give you the benefit of the doubt and presume that this is for the sake of "MCVE".  This then raises the question, "What *specifically* were you going to ask?"  We can likely help you write a more effective question if you actually provide us with details on what it is you're trying to express.

Comment: @JoeC and Patrice. sorry folks, but your humor is not related to my question.

Comment: @Makoto - Google provides an API for pacing of voice through Google Actions which supports SSML, at least how they tell. But actually, I have one snippet which sounds incorrect, maybe It's my fault but maybe a bug on their said - So my goal is to share SSML snippet with synthesized examples, and ask other developers which working with Google Actions. Google officially recommend to user Stackoverflow for this kind of questions.

Comment: 100% Eugene. Meta is a bit more lax about jokes, so apologies there. Anyway, the answer is what rene said. The best you can do would be to link the file in an external site. Now I happen to know a (not sure it's the only one) Voice Recognition API from Google (specifically the Speech API used by the Cloud Platform), and I can tell you that it's HIGHLY likely your file will be needed to reproduce, so I think your best bet is to link it. Then I would explain to users how to get it, in case they want to try. Depending on your issue they may be able to reproduce, or may need to have YOUR file

Comment: So did you ask this question in their support channels and get turned here instead?  This might change a few things.

Comment: @Patrice sure I have already mentioned that planned to give SSML snipped and attach a rendered file to people who want to try it quickly

Comment: @Makoto not really https://developers.google.com/actions/support/ but stackoverflow comes 1st when Google recommends asking the community. But sadly Stackoverflow doesn't look like right place to ask audio related questions

Comment: @EugeneKrevenets: We don't have a mechanism for posting databases or 3D meshes on SO. And yet, we have plenty of questions about databases and 3D mesh rendering. So it's clear that you don't need all the data files to be able to ask a question.

Comment: Sorry, but that support page sucks. It just implies to go to Stack Overflow to ask a question. There is a *little* bit more to it than that. Instead of going full steam ahead following what that page misinforms you to do, take a quick detour through the Stack Overflow help center first. It tells another story entirely, one more focused on searching for your answers before asking a question. There is also quite a list of rules about what questions not to ask.

Comment: @Gimby actually I've read StackOverflow help center and asked few different questions before this one. And I don't see any caveats that I can't ask for support and feature request of audio file attachment or anything else which could help to highlight an audio problem. I noted that StackOverflow could support more an audio-specific type of questions. It is a different kind of information and sometimes it hard to explain it in the words or images without hearing that sound. But it seems that folks here don't work with audio so they afraid this feature.

Comment: @EugeneKrevenets *"But it seems that folks here don't work with audio so they afraid this feature."* People here are many things, "afraid" generally does not fit the bill. Careful is a better phrasing.

Comment: @Gimby Sure! I didn't know it in advance and it was a big surprise for me too, but the most popular comment is:

"Am I the only one who finds the idea of Stack Overflow making noises at me rather frightening?"

And the meaning of "frightening" is "to make afraid or fearful; throw into a fright; terrify; scare."
(http://www.dictionary.com/browse/frightening).

So it would be better to say: "Because my question is the feature request of an audio attachment it is very likely that this feature frightening the biggest group of users here.". And I don't see any "up" votes here :(

Answer (score 6):

You can't.

Either link to it off-site but even better describe how users should recreate the MP3 if that is needed for testing.

Only a few sites in the network allow embedding of YouTube video's but this feature isn't enabled on Stack Overflow. There is [audio embedding](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72365/can-an-embedded-audio-player-be-added-to-audio-se-and-music-se) on [Music.se](https://music.stackexchange.com/) and [video.se](https://video.stackexchange.com/) (formerly audio.se, which merged into video) but again, the feature isn't enabled on Stack Overflow.

If you really have to you could create a Stack Snippet with the audio fragment base64 encoded but that gets messy for larger files:

```html
<audio src="data:audio/mp3;base64,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

" autoplay></audio>
Just click run code snippet
```

Here is a C# one liner to create an audio html tag for an arbitrary MP3 in LinqPad:

```
("<audio\r\nsrc=\"data:audio/mp3;base64,"+Convert.ToBase64String(new WebClient().DownloadData(@"https://cdn-chat.sstatic.net/chat/meta2.mp3"))+"\"\r\nautoplay>\r\n<audio>").Dump();
```

Comment: Are we allowed to add buttons like in `<audio src="[your .mp3 link]" preload controls></audio>` ? Thats to say, without encryption..

Comment: Hi @rene! Thanks for the answer! But I think many sites allow embedding youtube, soundcloud and many of other media sites. Because of iframe. So it is possible to support this feature here on stackoverflow as well. But sure it is not critical - but would be very helpful for audio related questions

Comment: @Subham inside a stack snippet you can do what ever you want. It is never run on load. The user need to click the Run Code snippet button. In the post it self only a limited set of tags is allowed. Audio, button, input or script are not among those allowed.

Comment: @EugeneKrevenets sure, Stack Overflow isn't in the group of websites that allow it.

Comment: @rene hm it is very interesting because Google recommends https://developers.google.com/actions/support/ stackoverflow like 1st place where developers should ask the community for help. Sure link to mp3 file works as well but makes it less smooth as it could be